# Nvidia quadro 2000 displayport not supporting 1440p

Tags: hdmi, displayport

My dads desktop has a nvidia quadro 2000 graphics card and he is trying to connect it to his new monitor, a dell S2719DM(2560x1440).
His old monitor(2560x1440) was connected to the quadro via a dual link dvi cable which worked perfectly. 
Now we have connected the new monitor, which only has hdmi inputs, to the quadro via a hdmi cable to a hdmi-displayport adapter(rated for 4k) but in the windows display settings we can only go up to 1920x1200. 
Wikipedia tells me that displayport should be able to easily support 2560x1440, but it seems that it does not.

Note. A normal displayport cable to the old monitor does not work at all, but the displayport-hdmi adapter with hdmi cable to either of the monitors does work,(although only up to 1920x1200).

My conclusion is that the quadro can’t output 2560x1440 on its displayport outputs but it can on its dvi output.

Is there someting i am missing?

Comment: "Support two active connectors including, dual-link DVI with up to 3840 x 2400 @ 24Hz on each panel, DisplayPort with up to up to 2560 x 1600, or HDMI for integrated audio and video thru the GPU." from https://www.nvidia.com/object/product-quadro-2000-us.html I'd suspect cable or converter not being up to spec.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using the HDMI input on your display, you do not (only) have a DisplayPort connection. You have a HDMI connection. HDMI in its most basic version is equivalent (in bandwidth) to a single DVI link. Which is obviously not enough for more than 1920x1200.

Another limiting factor is unfortunately the display itself, which may not support all resolutions with all HDMI versions. So even if HDMI 1.3 (what the Quadro supports) would theoretically support 2560x1440, if the display refuses to accept it, that’s that.

It is unclear what kind of adapter exactly you use. I seriously doubt it’s really “rated for 4K”. It may actually just be a passive adapter that relies in the DisplayPort output being able to switch to HDMI (DP++). If you want a more detailed assessment, you need to provide the make and model.

Your cheapest option, depending in the actual requirements, could be to simply buy a newer (possibly used) graphics card. That would then probably have less performance.

The Quadro definitely supports 2560x1440 with its DisplayPort output. It has DisplayPort 1.1a, which means it supports (uncompressed) up to 2560x1440 at 85 Hz. (Or 4K at 30 Hz.)

An adapter that would definitely do the job is the StarTech “DisplayPort to HDMI 2.0 Adapter – 4K 60Hz” (DP2HD4K60S). The Quadro cannot make full use of this adapter, because it only has DisplayPort 1.1a.

Comment: the new monitor, dell S2719DM, only has two inputs which are both hdmi 2.0. so the issue must be the hdmi->displayport converter, i've uploaded a picture of the box ( https://imgur.com/gallery/u3If3Rs ) for you. it clearly states 4k, this is a home brand from a big dutch webshop so i would expect it to be correct. Will try to find a hdmi to display port cable tomorrow at the office and try that before buying another gpu.

Comment: Please [add this information to your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1557950/edit). // It’s unfortunately impossible to get proper specs in this adapter. I don’t think it’s active though.

Comment: @longleggedlemon The photo says HDMI to Displayport converter. These converters aren't always bi-directional. Perhaps that's where the issue is.